# TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined (line 29 in function PGroup.has)

Tags: javascript, функции

Вот код класса:

```js
class PGroup {
  // Your code here
  constructor(members) {
    this.empty = members;
  }

  add(value) {
    if (this.has(value)) {
      return this;
    }
    return new PGroup(this.empty.concat[value]);
  }

  /*
                Its add method, however, should return a new PGroup instance with the given member added and leave the old one unchanged.
                Similarly, delete creates a new instance without a given member.
            */


  delete(value) {
    if (!this.has(value)) {
      return this;
    }
    this.empty = this.empty.filter((v) => v != value)
    return new PGroup(this.empty);
  }

  has(value) {
    return this.empty.includes(value);
  }

  static from(arr) {
    let gr = new Group();
    for (let i of arr) {
      gr.add(i);
    }
    return gr;
  }
}

PGroup.empty = new PGroup([]);
let a = PGroup.empty.add("a");
let ab = a.add("b");
let b = ab.delete("a");

console.log(b.has("b"));
// → true
console.log(a.has("b"));
// → false
console.log(b.has("a"));
// → false
```

Код ошибки:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined (line 29 in function PGroup.has) 
 called from line 8 in function PGroup.add
 called from line 44 in function eval
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в методе `.add`.

Метод [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) – это функция, в данном же случае

```
this.empty.concat[value]
```

Вместо вызова функции идет попытка получить значение свойства. Как результат, в большинстве случаев будет `undefined`.

Для решения достаточно заменить эту часть на вызов функции

```
this.empty.concat(value)
```

Пример, когда код мог работать:

```js
class PGroup {
  // Your code here
  constructor(members) {
    this.empty = members;
  }

  add(value) {
    if (this.has(value)) {
      return this;
    }
    return new PGroup(this.empty.concat[value]);
  }

  /*
                Its add method, however, should return a new PGroup instance with the given member added and leave the old one unchanged.
                Similarly, delete creates a new instance without a given member.
            */


  delete(value) {
    if (!this.has(value)) {
      return this;
    }
    this.empty = this.empty.filter((v) => v != value)
    return new PGroup(this.empty);
  }

  has(value) {
    return this.empty.includes(value);
  }

  static from(arr) {
    let gr = new Group();
    for (let i of arr) {
      gr.add(i);
    }
    return gr;
  }
}

PGroup.empty = new PGroup([]);
let a = PGroup.empty.add("name");

console.log(a.has("a"));
// → false
console.log(a.has("n"));
// → false
```

Comment: а почему в большинстве случаев?

Comment: @Alexander_Sky, потому что `concat` это обычная функция, и у нее есть все свойства, которые есть у других функций, например `.call`, `.name`, `.length` и другие

Comment: а можете привести конкретный пример, когда для моего кода при вызове того, что было выше, возвращается не undefined, а что-то другое

Comment: @Alexander_Sky, добавил пример

Comment: а можете детальней объяснить, почему в моем примере работает по цепочке, если заменить вызов свойства на вызов функции, вызов add, а в вашем нет?

Comment: @Alexander_Sky, в моем тоже работает, только для особенных параметров, о которых выше шла речь

Comment: Вы про .call, .name и другие свойства?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118789/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexander-sky).